# PHP: assign priority to array values and then sort by that priority

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is there a way to assign a "priority score" to an array in PHP?  Then sort based on that priority.  Given my input:

```
Array(
  [princeton] => Princeton
  [stanford] => Stanford
  [yale] => Yale
  [mit] => MIT
  [harvard] => Harvard 
)
```

I would like the output to always have `Harvard` and `Yale` at the top, the rest alphabetically sorted:

```
Array(
  [harvard] => Harvard
  [yale] => Yale
  [mit] => MIT
  [princeton] => Princeton
  [stanford] => Stanford    
)
```

I checked out `asort()` which does the alphabetical and `uasort()` which is custom-defined, but I'm stuck on how I can "assign a priority".  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where do the priorities come from?

Comment: I would handset them, there's only a couple, but I'm stuck at how to do the assigning.

Comment: removing and adding to top after sorting alphabetly seems trivial

Comment: With `uasort`, you would define the sorting between 2 items. If neither is Harvard or Yale, do a strcmp, if one of them is, make it sort before the other, if both are, return 0 (unless you want harvard to sort before yale always, in which case, you could once again return a strcmp when both are harvard or yale).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uasort` will sort your array by your own comparison function. I've made the function place either Harvard or Yale first (the ordering of those two will be uncertain since you haven't specified) and sort the rest alphabetically.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == 'Yale' || $a == 'Harvard') {
        return -1;
    } else if ($b == 'Yale' || $b == 'Harvard') {
        return 1;
    } else return strcmp($a, $b);
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were overthinking this.

1. sort by key
2. replace your short priority array with the alphabetized array

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0qrYj))

```
$ivyLeaguers = [
  'princeton' => 'Princeton',
  'cornell' => 'Cornell',
  'stanford' => 'Stanford',
  'yale' => 'Yale',
  'mit' => 'MIT',
  'harvard' => 'Harvard'
];

ksort($ivyLeaguers);
var_export(
    array_replace(['harvard' => null, 'yale' => null], $ivyLeaguers)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'harvard' => 'Harvard',
  'yale' => 'Yale',
  'cornell' => 'Cornell',
  'mit' => 'MIT',
  'princeton' => 'Princeton',
  'stanford' => 'Stanford',
)
```

The `null` values are overwritten but their position is respected.  This technique pulls the priority schools to the top of the list based on the matching keys.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like

```
$priotities=array(
  [harvard] => 1
  [yale] => 2
  [mit] => 3
  [princeton] => 4
  [stanford] => 5
)
```

you could

```
$final=$priorites;
sort(final);
foreach ($final as $k=>$v) 
  $final[$k]=$universities[$k];
```